# How to solve a scalene triangle with a given angle, side, and perimeter?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

[image]
We know $\angle A=31^{\circ}$ and side $AB$ has a length of $10$. Clearly, this isn't enough information to solve the triangle. But if we also know that the perimeter is $22$ (that is: $AB + BC + AC = 22$), I believe that should be solvable, as there can only be one line BC that intersects AC such that the perimeter is $22.$

I have tried bisecting the triangle into two right triangles and using trigonometry to find the unknown values, but I'm always left with too many variables to solve for.

Comment: What are we trying to solve here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $|AC|=x$ and $|BC|=12-x$. $~~(\because AB+BC+CA=22)$
Using the [cosine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines),
$$(12-x)^2=x^2+10^2-20x\cos31^{\circ}\implies x=\frac{44}{24-20\cos31^{\circ}}\approx 6.417.$$
The angles of the triangle can also be found using the [sine or cosine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines).

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that sine rule or cosine rule can be used again to find the remaining angles!

Comment: Maybe [something wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYtYe.png)....

Comment: @DatBoi Thanks. I have added it to my answer

Comment: Sorry I make a mistake in [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGqsY.png). You are right.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Law of cosines could come in handy

$AC^2 + 100 = BC^2- 20AC\cos 31$

$AC^2 + BC^2 = 100 - 2AC\cdot BC\cos \angle C$

$BC^2 + 100 = AC^2 - 20BC\cos \angle B$

with the restrictions $BC= 12-AC$ and $\angle C= 149- \angle B$ (and so $\cos \angle C= \cos B\cos 149 + \sin B\sin 149=-\cos B\cos 31 +\sin B\sin 31=-\cos B\cos 31 + \sqrt{1-\cos^2 B}\sin 31$

We now have three equations with essentially the two unknowns $BC$ and $\cos B$ (and everything is a positive value).